# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile'

Tags: android, gradle

When I sync the gradle files it is showing the error :

```
Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ompile()'
```

Possible causes:

The project 'Athletto' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I searched for various solutions but none of them worked.I don't know which plugin I have to use.Here are my gradle files :

build.gradle (Module ) :

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.hp.athletto"
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 16
                multiDexEnabled=true
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
            ompile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
            compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
            compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.6@aar') {
                transitive = true
            }
        }
```

build.gradle ( Project) :

```
            // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                mavenCentral()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typing error: change `ompile` to `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` on line 3 of dependencies.

```
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
            ompile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'//<--error here
            compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
            compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.6@aar') {
                transitive = true
            }
        }
```